# Set text align to left inside a dropdown?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a pure html and css dropdown and i am able to hide it and show it but i am not able to align the text inside the dropdown to left?

Can someone please point out to what i am doing wrong?

See this working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/bGwYmWp).

Or see this working example :-

```css
.toggle-dropdown p {
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 8%;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 8px #888888;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  display: none;
}

.toggle-dropdown:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>DropDown</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="toggle-dropdown">
    <p>Dropdown Text</p>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Messgaes</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contacts</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to set `padding-inline-start: 0;` in `ul` block:
In my forked codepen: https://codepen.io/adampweb/pen/MWjOPOO

```css
.toggle-dropdown p {
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 8%;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 8px #888888;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  display: none;
}

.toggle-dropdown:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

li a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>DropDown</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="toggle-dropdown">
    <p>Dropdown Text</p>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Messgaes</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contacts</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but `padding-left:0` also gave the same result. what's the difference between the two?

Comment: Look for this interactive explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline-start

Comment: In your case the `padding-left: 0` is also usable, but if you want to add a new language to your site such as Arabian, then the `padding-inline-start: 0;` is the better option